# No navigation arrows in fancybox, everything is grouoped in rel.. whats the issue?

Tags: fancybox

Everything work fine, without navigating arrows between videos and pictures
i have this in java in my website:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".fancyYoutube").click(function() {
    $.fancybox({
    'padding'       : 0,
    'autoScale'     : false,
    'overlayShow'   :   false,
    'transitionIn'      : 'elastic',
    'transitionOut'     : 'elastic',
    'showNavArrows'     : true,
    'title'     : this.title,
    'width'     : 680,
    'height'        : 495,
    'href'      : this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=","i"), 'v/'),
    'type'      : 'swf',
    'swf' : {
    'wmode' : 'transparent',
    'allowfullscreen' : 'true'
    }
    });
    return false;
    });
});
```

and this is my html code (section of mix videos/pictures):

```
<a class="fancyYoutube" title="KravMAGA" href="../img/auto.jpg" rel="grupa"><img src="http://i4.ytimg.com/vi/ci-pBX9lQKQ/default.jpg"></a>
        <a class="fancyYoutube" title="KRAVMAGA" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zcUUVHhlAjE&feature=plcp&autoplay=1" rel="grupa"><img src="http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/zcUUVHhlAjE/default.jpg"></a>
        <a class="fancyYoutube" title="KravMAGA" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zcUUVHhlAjE&feature=plcp&autoplay=1" rel="grupa"><img src="http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/bJCp9PW_KaA/default.jpg"></a>
        <a class="fancyYoutube" title="KRAVMAGA" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ci-pBX9lQKQ&autoplay=1" rel="grupa"><img src="http://i4.ytimg.com/vi/ci-pBX9lQKQ/default.jpg"></a>
        <a class="fancyYoutube" title="KravMAGA" href="../img/auto.jpg"><img src="http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/bJCp9PW_KaA/default.jpg"rel="grupa"></a>
```

And i dont have any navigation arrows, why ? in css everything is fine, every images (sprites) are in the same folder as fancybox.css
what i am doing wrong ?

```
#fancybox-left {
    left: -50px;
}

#fancybox-right {
right: -50px;
}
```

PLEASE HELP

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are using the manual method `.click()` with fancybox v1.3.4. There is no way to have a gallery like that unless you set it within the script like

```
$(".fancyYoutube").click(function(){
 $.fancybox([
  {"href": "TARGET HERE"},
  {"href": "TARGET HERE"} // more as you need them
 ],{
  // fancybox options here
 });
});
```

Additionally you are trying to set a gallery of different type of objects (images and video) with the same script, which is not possible either.

[Fancybox v2.x](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) has overcome those issues and you could easily set a gallery with the helper `fancybox-media`, but wondering if are considering to upgrade.

It would be as easy as keeping your current html and loading *fancybox.js* and *fancybox-media.js* files.

Then the script would be as simple as

```
$(".fancyYoutube").fancybox({
 helpers : { 
  media : {} 
 }
});
```

Comment: What i must to do to upgrade fancybox ? what to type in media and helpers ?

Comment: First, check the licensing options to see if they fit to your needs. Notice that if you upgrade, you have to remove the previous version files. Second, the script I set as example doesn't need anything else inside of it.

Comment: something like that ??                                 $(document).ready(function(){
 $(".fancyYoutube").click(function() {
 $.fancybox([
 {"href": "this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=","i"), 'v/')"}],{
 'padding'  : 0,
 'autoScale'  : false,
 'overlayShow' : false,
 'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
 'transitionOut'  : 'elastic',
 'cyclic'   : true,
 'showNavArrows'  : true,
 'title'  : this.title,
 'width'  : 680,
 'height'  : 495,
 'type'  : 'swf',
 'swf' : {
 'wmode' : 'transparent',
 'allowfullscreen' : 'true'
 }
 });
 return false;
 });
});
</script>

Comment: Do you want the code for v1.3.4 or for version 2 (if you are upgrading) ??

Answer (score 0):

For version 2 that would be like this - http://jsfiddle.net/nn4Tg/

You might want to use a media helper to make direct links work.